# how to replace values on a dataframe using pandas and streamlit in python?

Tags: python, pandas, replace, streamlit

i have a python script that read dataframe using pandas and display its content  using streamlit.

What i want is to replace **current value** with a **new value** based on the user input.

Where user **select the required column** and than enter the **current value** in a text field than the **new value** in the second text field  when  button **replace** is pressed the **old value** is replaced by the **new value** and the new dataframe is displayed.

**the problem is that when it display the dataframe nothing is changed**

## code:

```
import pandas as pd 
import streamlit as st 


df =pd.DataFrame({
            "source_number":                        [ 
             [11199,11328,11287,32345,12342,1232,13456,123244,13456],
             "location":          
             ["loc2","loc1","loc3","loc1","loc2","loc2","loc3","loc2","loc1"],
              "category": 
             ["cat1","cat2","cat1","cat3","cat3","cat3","cat2","cat3","cat2"],
             })  

columns = st.selectbox("Select  column", df.columns)
old_values = st.multiselect("Current Values",list(df[columns].unique()),list(df[columns].unique()))
col1,col2 = st.beta_columns(2)
with col1:
     old_val = st.text_input("old value")
with col2:
     new_val = st.text_input("new value")
if st.button("Replace"):
      df[columns]=df[columns].replace({old_val:new_val})
      st.dataframe(df)
```

Comment: What errors are you getting @user5980666? It may not be the only problem, but when you are creating the dataframe you have an extra square bracket on the beginning.

Comment: @GonçaloPeres龚燿禄 where i have an extra square brackets??

and why this line may be problematic ??

i used the `replace` function is this wrong ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a little error in your code.

> df[columns]=df[columns].replace({old_val:new_val})

When you look at a pandas docs in examples there is a code like that

> s.replace({'a': None}) - it replaces value 'a' with None value

When looking at your code what it means, that you are trying to replace value that is a list with another list, but it does not work like that, because your column doesn't have a list as an element so can't change it like that.
When I ran your code in Jupyter I got an error that list is unhashable

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-41a02888936d> in <module>
     30 oldVal = [11199,11328,11287,32345]
     31 
---> 32 df["source_number"] = df["source_number"].replace({oldVal:newVal})
     33 df

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

And this a reason why it doesn't change anything for you.

If you want to change all values using lists you will have to write it like that:

```
df[column] = df[column].replace(old_values, new_values)
```

This code works just fine.

I hope I was clear enough and it will work for you.

Comment: you were right thank for the help but how to save the change to the original dataframe ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for **text** columns (`location` and `category`). It doesn't work for the **numeric** `source_number` column as you're trying to replace one **string** by another.

For numeric columns you'll need to use `number_input` instead of `text_input`:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.api.types import is_numeric_dtype
import streamlit as st


df = pd.DataFrame({
            "source_number":
             [11199,11328,11287,32345,12342,1232,13456,123244,13456],
             "location":
             ["loc2","loc1","loc3","loc1","loc2","loc2","loc3","loc2","loc1"],
              "category":
             ["cat1","cat2","cat1","cat3","cat3","cat3","cat2","cat3","cat2"],
             })

columns = st.selectbox("Select  column", df.columns)
old_values = st.multiselect("Current Values",list(df[columns].unique()),list(df[columns].unique()))
col1,col2 = st.beta_columns(2)
st_input = st.number_input if is_numeric_dtype(df[columns]) else st.text_input
with col1:
     old_val = st_input("old value")
with col2:
     new_val = st_input("new value")
if st.button("Replace"):
     df[columns]=df[columns].replace({old_val:new_val})
     st.dataframe(df)
```

---

Update as per comment: you could cache the `df` to prevent re-initalization upon each widget interaction (you'll have to manually clear the cache to start over):

```
@st.cache(allow_output_mutation=True)
def get_df():
   return pd.DataFrame({
            "source_number":
             [11199,11328,11287,32345,12342,1232,13456,123244,13456],
             "location":
             ["loc2","loc1","loc3","loc1","loc2","loc2","loc3","loc2","loc1"],
              "category":
             ["cat1","cat2","cat1","cat3","cat3","cat3","cat2","cat3","cat2"],
             })

df = get_df()
```

Comment: how to save the new value to the original dataframe ??

Comment: `df[columns]=df[columns].replace({old_val:new_val})` saves the new value to the original dataframe. You might get the impression that it doesn't as streamit re-run your entire script on each input, so you each time create a new (original) dataframe.

Comment: but after i finish this task and try to re-select a column the  `old value`  still exist in  
 `multiselectbox`  without the `new one`

Comment: [every widget interaction causes a rerun of the app](https://docs.streamlit.io/en/stable/advanced_concepts.html?highlight=re-run#batch-elements-and-input-widgets), so when you open the `multiselectbox` it re-initialized the dataframe.